# sklearn, DecisionTreeRegressor: Can I give priority to one column of the data over the other columns?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

[Image tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aYkP.png)

I'm making a decision Tree based on a dataset with 3 columns:

example:

```
ID  Area  Year

1     50   1950

2      150   1981

3      210   1987

4      205   1973

5      176   1992
```

....

When I make a decision tree  using the DecisionTreeRegressor, this tree is based on all 3 columns, what I want is that the ID is not included in the tree itself but can still be traced back (so I don't want to delete this column)

Furthermore, I also want that the column 'Year' has a priority compared to the column 'Area'. So the total number of data is first split according to the year, and afterwards to the 'Year'.  (now the decisiontree decided to make 'Area' (X[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aYkP.png)) prior, and 'Year' is not even used... See image attached: [Image tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aYkP.png))

How can I do this?

I tried to convert the first column to a string, but the tree is still using column 'ID'.

---

My code so far:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(min_samples_split=20,max_leaf_nodes=20).fit(X_train, y_train)
tree.plot_tree(clf)

import os

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'C:\anaconda3\Library\bin\graphviz'

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None) 

graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data) 

from graphviz import render

graph.render('png', "test")
```

Comment: Could you show some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Show us what you tried. SO is not a free code service site .

Comment: Methods on the classifier like `predict` and `predict_proba` maintain the order of rows - i.e. even if you delete the ID column from your `X_train` dataset (while maintaining it in some base dataset) - you can simply concatenate the predicted values later

Comment: The whole point of decision trees is to leave them decide the optimal split according to their own criteria; there is no point in trying to give them "priorities" manually.

Comment: Thank you @Mortz!

Answer (score -1):

Methods on the classifier like `predict` and `predict_proba` maintain the order of rows - i.e. even if you delete the `ID` column from your `X_train` dataset (while maintaining it in some base dataset) - you can simply concatenate the predicted values later.

W.r.t your question on how to split by `Year` first - I don't think `sklearn` or any of the other python ML libraries can do this. You would want to look at alternatives like *SAS Enterprise Miner* OR *Angoss Knowledge Studio* - but neither of them are FOSS.

A dirty hack could be to build a tree with just the `Year` column - note the splits and then segment your data into 2 (or more) parts based on the splits obtained.